# Table's searchbar at the top without scrolling

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, ios5, uisearchbar

Is it possible to move a have a search bar at the top of a table and avoid it scrolling in IOS5?

Like this, the arrow show where I want to have searcher
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one approach would be to situate a UISearchBar outside the UITableView.  Then it obviously will not scroll with the table view.

If you want to use UISearchDisplayController (and get all the nice animations that come with it), I think you will have a tougher time.